# Generics: The type 'Camera' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type

Tags: c#, generics

```
interface IResourceProperties
{
}

class TopLevelResource<T> 
where T: IResourceProperties
{

}

class Camera: TopLevelResource<CameraProperties>
{
}

class CameraProperties : IResourceProperties
{
}

class Phone: TopLevelResource<PhoneProperties>
{
}

class PhoneProperties : IResourceProperties
{
}

void Main()
{
 List<Camera> cameras = new List<Camera>();
 List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>();
 DoSomething(cameras);
 DoSomething(phones);
}

void DoSomething<T>(List<T> items)
where T: TopLevelResource<IResourceProperties>
{
  return;
}
```

I have the above mentioned class hierarchy.
Generic method `DoSomething` needs to be able to work on both Cameras and Phones.
But I am getting the following error:

> The type 'Camera' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic
>   type or method 'DoSomething(System.Collections.Generic.List)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Server' to
>   'TopLevelResource'.

Which suggests this is not possible.

What is the best option to be able to write DoSomething generically and handle both Phones and Cameras together.

Comment: Where's the type Server coming from? Are you getting this error when compiling or at run-time? Is this when you're trying to call the DoSomething method?

Comment: I ignored the `Server` error as a red herring - assuming that the code posted was a simplification of the actual code in use.

Comment: fixed. its actually Camera not Server

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that `TopLevelResource` is not working [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)ly, i.e. `TopLevelResource<PhoneProperties>` is not `TopLevelResource<IResourceProperties>`.

You can fix this by having an `IDevice` interface which `Phone` and `Camera` derive from:

`interface IDevice<out T> where T : IResourceProperties`

Note that `IDevice` is `<out T>` so it is a [variant generic interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx).

An example of another interface which has `<out T>` is [`IEnumerable<out T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0). If `TDerived : TBase`, then an `IEnumerable<TDerived>` is also `IEnumerable<TBase>` and `IEnumerable<object>`

Your code would be:

```
interface IResourceProperties
{ }

interface IDevice<out T>
    where T : IResourceProperties
{ }

class TopLevelResource<T> : IDevice<T>
    where T : IResourceProperties
{ }

class Camera : TopLevelResource<CameraProperties>
{ }

class Phone : TopLevelResource<PhoneProperties>
{ }

class CameraProperties : IResourceProperties
{ }

class PhoneProperties : IResourceProperties
{ }

internal class Runner
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        List<Camera> cameras = new List<Camera>();
        List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>();
        DoSomething(cameras);
        DoSomething(phones);
    }

    static void DoSomething<T>(List<T> items)
        where T : IDevice<IResourceProperties>
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or implement IResourceProperties in Phone and Camera

```
interface IResourceProperties
{
}

class TopLevelResource<T> 
where T: IResourceProperties
{

}

class Camera: TopLevelResource<CameraProperties>, IResourceProperties
{
}

class CameraProperties : IResourceProperties
{
}

class Phone: TopLevelResource<PhoneProperties>, IResourceProperties
{
}

class PhoneProperties : IResourceProperties
{
}



    class Program
    {static void DoSomething<T>
        (List<T> items) where T : IResourceProperties
    {
  return;
}
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             List<Camera> cameras = new List<Camera>();
 List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>();
 DoSomething(cameras);
 DoSomething(phones);
        }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: But now *both* `Phone` and `PhoneProperties` implement `IResourceProperties`. While the interface doesn't have anything in it, that's okay, but once there's some implementation, this won't work.